# PHP Converting a date to timestamp using DateTime decreases 1 day - weird

Tags: php

Have the following simple PHP code:

```
$day = '2013-05-04';
$disp_day = DateTime::createFromFormat('U', strtotime($day));
echo $day . " " . $disp_day->format('F j');
```

It outputs

```
2013-05-04 May 3
```

But `$disp_date` should be May 4 right?

Comment: @Pekka웃 Please explain...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a timezone issue.

`strtotime` will give you a timezone senstitive timestamp, while `createFromFormat` with the `U` parameter will interpret the timestamp as GMT.

- I'm guessing your time zone is India (GMT + 5.5). Hence, `strtotime("2013-05-04")` will get you a timestamp that in *India* is `2013-05-04 00:00`. However, in GMT, where it's five and a half hours earlier, the time is  `2013-05-03 18:30`.
- You are then passing this Indian timestamp *as GMT* to CreateFromFormat, leading to the shift.

There is no need to use `strtotime` here at all: just do

```
DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', $day);
```

Comment: What is the best possible way to convert a string date `2013-05-04` to a DateTime object without going through timezone hassles?

Comment: While you've hit upon the correct solution, the explanation doesn't add up - or maybe I'm just being very slow.

Comment: @Strawberry yeah, pondering over the same thing - gimme a minute (I think the OP's actual time zone might be in India, GMT +5.5)

Comment: @Strawberry I think I got it now

Comment: But I'm 7 miles from Greenwich, and I get the same result !?! ;-)

Comment: @Strawberry that's because you're on [BST](http://www.timeanddate.com/library/abbreviations/timezones/eu/bst.html) - it's just 1 hour in your case, but the same phenomenon. When it's midnight in Britain, it's only 23:00 in GMT.

Comment: Ah, because it deducts an hour from midnight!

Comment: @Straw yup. (it's no good mixing the two date libraries, exactly for reasons like these)

Comment: So the issue isn't so much your longitude as your proximity to the equator! ;-)